# Remove focus from tab control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a tab control on my page with two tabs. When I click on the second tab, the page scrolls down to the tab control. I don't want to have any focus on the tab control and maintain the page where it was. I know it happens due to the href on the `<li>` but if I remove the href I don't see any data.

My html code is as below:

```
<div id="tabContainer" class="Container">
  <ul class="maintabs">
    <li><a href="#tabDescription" class="active">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabTerms">Terms</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabDetails">
    <div id="tabDescription" class="tabContents">
      <div id="divDescription" runat="server"></div>               
    </div>
    <div id="tabTerms" class="tabContents">
      <div id="divterms" runat="server"></div>
    </div>                            
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tabContents").hide(); 
            $(".tabContents:first").show(); 

            $("#tabContainer ul li a").click(function () { 

                var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
                $("#tabContainer ul li a").removeClass("active"); 
                $(this).addClass("active"); 
                $(".tabContents").hide(); 
                $(activeTab).show(); 
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the default behavior of the link from occurring.

For your click action, accept the first argument, `e` (for event) and call JQuery's [`preventDefault` function](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on it.  This will stop the browser from following the link.

```
$("#tabContainer ul li a").click(function (e) {
    // hey browser, don't handle this link--we'll take it from here
    e.preventDefault();

    // ...
});
```

You can call that anywhere in the function (e.g., at the end).